# Implementing piwik.js custom event sending to service

Tags: matomo

Is it possible to use Piwik for tracking but to process and send events to custom service instead of Piwik one?
Also make POST instead of GET requests to service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, something like that is possible. Piwik has setCustomRequestProcessing function. That function lets you edit the tracking request before it is sent. 
As far as POST, you can get query parameters from piwiks tracking request. Something like this:

```
var getQueryParameters = function (hash) {
    var split = hash.split('&');

    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
       var kv = split[i].split('=');
       obj[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1] ? kv[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ') : kv[1]);
    }
    return obj;
};
```